# Adding annotation to the below pivoted column chart dynamically - google api

Tags: javascript, json, charts, annotations, google-visualization

I've created the below code example which is showing the sales quantity for two products I need to display the quantity value on each column please help..

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #U{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        height: 500px;
        color: black;
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"label":"REPLACE DATE","type":"string"},{"label":"ITEM","type":"number"},{"label":"QUANTITY REPLACED","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"01\/29"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":11}]},{"c":[{"v":"01\/29"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"01\/30"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":136}]},{"c":[{"v":"01\/30"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":94}]},{"c":[{"v":"01\/31"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":130}]},{"c":[{"v":"01\/31"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":87}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/01"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":127}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/01"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":100}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/02"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":114}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/02"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":89}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/03"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":131}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/03"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":145}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/04"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":142}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/04"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":139}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/05"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":12}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/05"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":27}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/06"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":146}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/06"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":99}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/07"},{"v":"IN-U-1"},{"v":219}]},{"c":[{"v":"02\/07"},{"v":"IN-U-2"},{"v":171}]}]});
    var options = {
            title: 'Sales',
            vAxis: {title: "Quantity", gridlines: { count: 6 }},
            hAxis: {title: "Per Day"},
            //is3D: 'true',
            chartArea: {'top': '30','left':'100'},
            bar: { groupWidth: "80%" },
            //annotations.alwaysOutside: true,
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
        };

    /* pivot the data table
     * set column A as the first column in the view, 
     * then we have to separate out the C values into their own columns
     * according to the value of B, using a DataView with calculated columns
     */

    // get all the values in column B
    // this sorts the values in lexicographic order, so if you need a different order you have to build the array appropriately
    var distinctValues = data.getDistinctValues(1);

    var viewColumns = [0];
    var groupColumns = [];
    // build column arrays for the view and grouping
    for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
        viewColumns.push({
            type: 'number',
            label: distinctValues[i],
            calc: (function (x) {
                return function (dt, row) {
                    // return values of C only for the rows where B = distinctValues[i] (passed into the closure via x)
                    return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == x) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
                }
            })(distinctValues[i])
        });
        groupColumns.push({
            column: i + 1,
            type: 'number',
            label: distinctValues[i],
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
        });
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    // next, we group the view on column A, which gets us the pivoted data
    var pivotedData = google.visualization.data.group(view, [0], groupColumns);


    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('U'));
    chart.draw(pivotedData, options, {});

}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="U"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help... 
Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Hisham

Comment: You need to provide way more details for the amount of code you posted.

Comment: such as dear Sterling? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Labeling Bars](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#labeling-bars)...

Basically, just add another view column for the annotation...

```
{
  calc: 'stringify',  
  sourceColumn: 1,    // identify column value to be displayed
  type: 'string',     
  role: 'annotation'
}
```

In this case, you may need to create another view off of `pivotedData`

Comment: Yes WhiteHat I've checked the labeling bars link but i don't know how to do it please help.. how can i make another view for the pivotedData ?

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat i made it :)